# Upload upto 400MB size file to ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, file-upload, streaming, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and this is my code for Upload File(Video) from client-side. My Problem is up to 10MB upload took too much time. Is there any way to upload through a stream or any other best practice?

My required File Size is up to 400MB.

```cs
/// <response code="200">If all working fine</response>
/// <response code="403">If client made some mistake</response>  
/// <response code="500">If Server Error</response>  
[ProducesResponseType(200)]
[ProducesResponseType(403)]
[ProducesResponseType(500)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Response<List<FileUrlResponce>>), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Response<List<FileUrlResponce>>), 403)]
[CustomAuthorize(false)]
[HttpPost]
[Route("uploadmedias3")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadMediaS3([FromForm]UploadDocuments param, IFormFile mediaFile)
{
    try
    {
        var response = new List<FileUrlResponce>();
        FileUrlResponce vedioFile = new FileUrlResponce();

        var fileName = mediaFile.FileName;
        if (param.Type == (int)EDocumentType.Image)
        {
            var file = await new SaveFiles().SendMyFileToS3(mediaFile, configuration.GetValue<string>("Amazon:Bucket"), "ProfilePicture", false, configuration.GetValue<string>("Amazon:AccessKey"), configuration.GetValue<string>("Amazon:AccessSecret"), configuration.GetValue<string>("Amazon:BaseUrl"));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.URL))
            {
                file.URL = file.URL;
                response.Add(file);
            }
        }
        else if (param.Type == (int)EDocumentType.Video)
        {
            vedioFile = await new SaveFiles().SendMyFileToS3(mediaFile, configuration.GetValue<string>("Amazon:Bucket"), "ProfilePicture", true, configuration.GetValue<string>("Amazon:AccessKey"), configuration.GetValue<string>("Amazon:AccessSecret"), configuration.GetValue<string>("Amazon:BaseUrl"));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vedioFile.URL) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(vedioFile.ThumbUrl))
            {
                response.Add(vedioFile);
            }
        }
        else if (param.Type == (int)EDocumentType.Document)
        {
            var file = await new SaveFiles().SendMyFileToS3(mediaFile, configuration.GetValue<string>("Amazon:Bucket"), "ProfilePicture", true, configuration.GetValue<string>("Amazon:AccessKey"), configuration.GetValue<string>("Amazon:AccessSecret"), configuration.GetValue<string>("Amazon:BaseUrl"));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.URL))
            {
                file.URL = file.URL;
                response.Add(file);
            }
        }

        if (response.Any())
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new Response<List<FileUrlResponce>>() { isError = false, messages = "", data = response });
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden, new Response<List<FileUrlResponce>>() { isError = true, messages = Error.FileNotFound, data = new List<FileUrlResponce>() });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

SaveFile().SendMyFileToS3() => Method Code Total time Upload on server then s3 is 2-3 mints for 84MB with broadband speed 10MB/s

```
      public async Task<FileUrlResponce> SendMyFileToS3(IFormFile file, string bucketName, string subDirectoryInBucket, bool isVedio, string accessKey, string accessSecret, string baseUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            FileUrlResponce reponse = new FileUrlResponce();
            var FileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            using (var source = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                source.Position = 0; Stream thumbStream = new MemoryStream(); source.CopyTo(thumbStream); var client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, accessSecret, RegionEndpoint.USEast1); PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = subDirectoryInBucket + "/" + FileName,
                    InputStream = source,
                    ContentType = file.ContentType,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                }; PutObjectResponse response = await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequest);

                reponse.URL = baseUrl + putRequest.Key;

                if (!isVedio)
                {
                    thumbStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    thumbStream.Position = 0;

                    Bitmap srcBmp = new Bitmap(thumbStream);
                    float ratio = 1;
                    float minSize = Math.Min(256, 256);

                    if (srcBmp.PropertyIdList.Contains(0x112)) //0x112 = Orientation
                    {
                        var prop = srcBmp.GetPropertyItem(0x112);
                        if (prop.Type == 3 && prop.Len == 2)
                        {
                            UInt16 orientationExif = BitConverter.ToUInt16(srcBmp.GetPropertyItem(0x112).Value, 0);
                            if (orientationExif == 8)
                            {
                                srcBmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
                            }
                            else if (orientationExif == 3)
                            {
                                srcBmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
                            }
                            else if (orientationExif == 6)
                            {
                                srcBmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (srcBmp.Width > srcBmp.Height)
                    {
                        ratio = minSize / (float)srcBmp.Width;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ratio = minSize / (float)srcBmp.Height;
                    }

                    SizeF newSize = new SizeF(srcBmp.Width * ratio, srcBmp.Height * ratio);
                    Bitmap target = new Bitmap((int)newSize.Width, (int)newSize.Height);


                    Stream saveableThumbStream = new MemoryStream();

                    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(target))
                    {
                        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
                        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                        graphics.DrawImage(srcBmp, 0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height);
                        graphics.Dispose();

                        target.Save(saveableThumbStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);


                    }

                    PutObjectRequest putRequestThumb = new PutObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = bucketName,
                        Key = subDirectoryInBucket + "/thumb_" + FileName,
                        InputStream = saveableThumbStream,
                        ContentType = file.ContentType,
                        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
                    };
                    PutObjectResponse responseThumb = await client.PutObjectAsync(putRequestThumb);

                    reponse.ThumbUrl = baseUrl + putRequestThumb.Key;
                }
                else
                {
                    reponse.ThumbUrl = baseUrl + putRequest.Key;
                }

            }
            return reponse;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
    }
```

Comment: `My Problem is Upto 10MB Upload took too much time,` How long did it take?

Comment: I took two minutes on 84MB file

Comment: Where's the code for `SaveFiles`

Comment: And where was the 2 minutes spent? Which bit was slow? What is your broadband speed (upload and download)?

Comment: Question is Updated with SAVEFILE Code

Comment: broadband speed is 10MB/s active taking from www.speedtest.net

Comment: Is There any way o can stream file to a server?

Comment: OK, so let's assume you mean 10Mb (not MB) per second (since that is how speedtest shows numbers). So that is a max upload speed of 75 MB a minute (10 * 60 / 8). So 2 minutes doesn't seem _crazy_ (you won't get it under 70 seconds).

Comment: Thanx, I will remember that,
ok, then what is the solution of this error, please guide me,
Also if any other good practice except or with Stream approach in ASP.NET CORE 3.1 

8/12/2020 5:29:18 AM ==>   Error: The client has disconnected
8/12/2020 5:43:09 AM ==>  Error: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
8/12/2020 6:40:05 AM ==> Error: The request was aborted
8/12/2020 6:53:20 AM ==> Error: Request body too large.